# Extracting Day out of Timestamp in Microstrategy

Tags: oracle, timestamp, microstrategy

I have a timestamp field in Microstrategy and want to extract the day , year and month from it.

A valid Excel expression that works is

```
ApplySimple("Month(#0)", [FIELD_TO_BE_WORKED])
```

What would be the corresponding expression for Oracle ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to use the Lalit suggestions, for the Month you can use the following `ApplySimple` formulas:

1.

```
ApplySimple("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM #0)", [FIELD_TO_BE_WORKED])
```

2.

```
ApplySimple("TO_CHAR(#0,'Month')", [FIELD_TO_BE_WORKED])
```

3.

```
ApplySimple("TO_CHAR(#0,'Mon')", [FIELD_TO_BE_WORKED])
```

Comment: thanks! this works. Also , if I want to get the current year - what wuold the ApplySimple formula be ?

Comment: you should use, YEAR in the first solution or 'yyyy' in the second and third

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, pick what you want from the list :

1.

```
SQL> SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSTIMESTAMP) THE_DAY,
  2  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSTIMESTAMP) THE_MONTH,
  3  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP) THE_YEAR
  4  FROM DUAL
  5  /

   THE_DAY  THE_MONTH   THE_YEAR
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10       2014

SQL>
```

2.

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'Day') THE_DAY,
  2  TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'Month') THE_MONTH,
  3  to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP,'Year') THE_YEAR
  4  FROM DUAL
  5  /

THE_DAY   THE_MONTH THE_YEAR
--------- --------- ------------------------------------------
Wednesday October   Twenty Fourteen
```

3.

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'Dy') THE_DAY,
  2  TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'Mon') THE_MONTH,
  3  to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP,'YYYY') THE_YEAR
  4  FROM DUAL
  5  /

THE THE THE_
--- --- ----
Wed Oct 2014
```